Was "Goliath" supposed to end at season 3?
Season 3 of Goliath ends with the ending of many story threads, including ones from previous seasons (Obviously spoilers below):

The current case is closed with Billy's winning a large payout for the people in town and his friend.
Marisol Silva, who previously outplayed Billy is forced to quit her job as a mayor and is pending a criminal trial.
Patty not only found her biological mother but is expecting her own child.
Brittany and Denise won't be following in Billy's footsteps.
Donald is humiliated yet once again.

But most importantly (here I need the spoiler formatting)

Billy is shot and the prophecy of "seeing his own face before death" is fulfilled, when he lies dying in a puddle of water.

And then we have season 4, which seems to ignore most of the outcomes of the previous ending: Billy is well (at least physically, as he has lots of weird nightmares), Patty's pregnancy is mentioned offhandedly once (she miscarried), and Donald suddenly appears as an ally...
Was the show planned for only 3 seasons and then added another one when the show became successful?

It seems that the show was intended for four seasons according to Newsweek.

Thornton also confirmed he only ever signed up for four seasons and that it was always the long-term plan to complete those four seasons of Goliath.

Given that statement it seems unlikely that only three seasons were planned if the principal actor signed up for four.

I'm not sure if the first part is evidence of anything. Lots of actors are optioned and contracted for multiple seasons of shows that never had much chance of getting future seasons.

Noted but the last part would indicate that the plan was for four seasons (at most). Granted there is always the possibility of cancellation but that didn't happen. You could posit that the writers gave themselves an out by wrapping up plot threads in S3 but I can't find anything (yet) to indicate that S4 wasn't planned.

Looking at the Wikipedia info, it seems that the decisions were made season-by-season and ending at season 4 was made due to Thornton personal decision [https://www.newsweek.com/billy-bob-thornton-explains-why-goliath-ending-after-season-4-1631801#:~:text=The%20quality%20of%20the%20show,right%20to%20end%20it%20here.%22]
